# Angular NodeJS cookie credentials. Why use client cookie?

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, express-session

I'm struggling with understanding cookie credentials in detail.
The main issue is that my frontend and backend run on different domains. On localhost, they have different ports (localhost:4200 and localhost:3000), and on my server different subdomain (example.com and api.example.com).

**Basic setup:**

Angular send post request to login:

```
this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'users', credentials)
```

NodeJS validates the request and creates an express-session (session in DB and cookie with sessionId):

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: mongoDBStore,
    name: 'node_session',
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000
    }
}));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // some validations
    req.session.userId = result._id;
    res.send(result._id);
}
```

**My understanding**

From my understanding cookies get stored for the server domain. So if both run on the same domain, on each request, the backend can use the session cookie. But with different domains, the session is empty on further requests.

Additionally, I found the cookie node_session in the frontend and backend. So if I add { withCredentials: true } to the requests of Angular, everything works. But in this case, I use the cookie from the frontend.

**My Questions:**

Is it secure to use the frontend cookie?

Why can I find the session cookie in the frontend and backend?

Why is my backend unable to find the session cookie?

Answer (score 0):

session information is stored on the backend. frontend just stores uniq session identifier in cookies. If you want to understand somehow that requests came from the same user one of the options is to use `{withCredentials: true}`, without it cookies are just not saved to the client, and backend can not define, whether different queries were send by one client or not.

as an alternative to cookies there is a popular option to use authorization token, but it is a bit more difficult to setup

Comment: HI thank you for the answer. So it means without {withcredentials:true} it can't work, except the frontend and backend runs on the same domain?

Comment: it can work, but you need to define which client executes the query. sending cookies is the simplest possible way, but you can also send this information in headers. popular way is send `Autorization: Bearer token` header with every request